# Skip directory name in import path by importing subpackage in __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm baffled by the importing dynamics in `__init__.py`.
Say I have this structure:

```
package
├── __init__.py
└── subpackage
    ├── __init__.py
    └── dostuff.py
```

I would like to import things in `dostuff.py`. I could do it like this: `from package.subpackage.dostuff import thefunction`, but I would like to remove the `subpackage` level in the import statement, so it would look like this:

```py
from package.dostuff import thefunction
```

I tried putting this in `package/__init__.py`:

```py
from .subpackage import dostuff
```

And what I don't understand is this:

```py
# doing this works:
from package import dostuff
dostuff.thefunction()

# but this doesn't work:
from package.dostuff import thefunction
# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package.dostuff'
```

Why is that, and how can I make `from package.dostuff import thefunction` work?

Comment: If you want to be able to do `from package.dostuff import thefunction` you have to have a module named `package.dostuff`.

Comment: But by putting `dostuff` in the package's `__init__.py` shouldn't it be accessible? It is accessible by doing `from package import dostuff`

Comment: I have solved a similar problem with symlinks. If you create a symlink named dostuff in package, pointing to .subpackages/dostuff.py it should work

Comment: Feel free to add this as one of the possible answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I see to make what you intend would be to actually create a `package/dostuff.py` module and import all you need in it as `from .subpackage.dostuff import thefunction`.

The point is that when you use `from .subpackage import dostuff` in `package/__init__.py`, you do not rename the original module.

To be more explicit, here is an example of use with both your import and a `package/dostuff.py` file:

```
# We import the dostuff link from package
>>> from package import dostuff
>>> dostuff
<module 'package.subpackage.dostuff' from '/tmp/test/package/subpackage/dostuff.py'>

# We use our custom package.dostuff
>>> from package.dostuff import thefunction
>>> package.dostuff
<module 'package.dostuff' from '/tmp/test/package/dostuff.py'>
>>> from package import dostuff
>>> dostuff
<module 'package.dostuff' from '/tmp/test/package/dostuff.py'>

# The loaded function is the same
>>> dostuff.thefunction
<function thefunction at 0x7f95403d2730>
>>> package.dostuff.thefunction
<function thefunction at 0x7f95403d2730>
```

#### A clearer way of putting this is:

`from X import Y` only works when **X** is an actual module path. 
**Y** on the contrary can be any item imported in this module.

This also applies to packages with anything being declared in their `__init__.py`. Here you declare the module `package.subpackage.dostuff` in `package`, hence you can import it and use it.

But if you try to use the module for a direct import, it has to exist on the filesystem

#### Resources:

- Python documentation about module management in the import system:

  - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules.
- Python import system search behavior:

  - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching
  - https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name
  - https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html

I hope that makes it clearer

Comment: It could be a solution but it looks a bit like a workaround to me. Also I'm not sure I understand `from package.dostuff import thefunction` if I import `thefunction` in `package/__init__.py`

Comment: `from X import Y` only works when X is an actual module *path*. Y on the contrary can be any item imported in this module. This also applies to packages with anything being declared in their `__init__.py`. Here you declare the module `package.subpackage.dostuff` in `package`, hence you can import it and use it. But if you try to use the module for a direct import, it has to exist on the filesystem.

Comment: If you could edit your answer with that comment and a source in the docs you'd deserve the bounty!

Comment: I updated the answer, is there enough information for you ? :)

Comment: I may be perfectionist but I still can’t figure out why « from c import y only works when X is an actual module path »

Comment: I found a more explicit documentation in the python 2 doc: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/import.html

Comment: The same doc for Python3: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

Answer (score 2):

You *can* in fact fake this quite easily by fiddling with Python's `sys.modules` dict. The question is whether you do really need this or whether it might be good to spend a second thought on your package structure.

Personally, I would consider this bad style, because it applies magic to the module and package names and people who might use and extend your package will have a hard time figuring out what's going on there.

Following your structure above, add the following code to your `package/__init__.py`:

```
import sys

from .subpackage import dostuff

# This will be package.dostuff; just avoiding to hard-code it.
_pkg_name = f"{__name__}.{dostuff.__name__.rsplit('.', 1)[1]}"

if _pkg_name not in sys.modules.keys():
    dostuff.__name__ = _pkg_name  # Will have no effect; see below
    sys.modules[_pkg_name] = dostuff
```

This imports the `dostuff` module from your `subpackage` to the scope of `package`, changes its module path and adds it to the imported modules. Essentially, this just copies the binding of your module to another import path where member memory addresses remain the same. You just duplicate the references:

```
import package
print(package.dostuff)
print(package.subpackage.dostuff)
print(package.dostuff.something_to_do)
print(package.subpackage.dostuff.something_to_do)
```

... yields

```
<module 'package.subpackage.dostuff' from '/path/package/subpackage/dostuff.py'>
<module 'package.subpackage.dostuff' from '/path/package/subpackage/dostuff.py'>
<function something_to_do at 0x1029b8ae8>
<function something_to_do at 0x1029b8ae8>
```

Note that

1. The module name `package.subpackage.dostuff` has not changed even though being updated in `package/__init__.py`
2. The function reference is the same: `0x1029b8ae8`

Now, you can also go

```
from package.dostuff import something_to_do
something_to_do()
```

However, be cautious. Changing the imported modules during import of a module might have unintended side-effects (also the order of updating `sys.modules` and importing other subpackages or submodules from within `package` might be relevant). Usually, you buy extra work and extra complexity by applying such kind of "improvement". Better yet set up a proper package structure and stick to it.

Comment: In my case `package` is the name of a repository I intend to use as a git submodule within another repository. I want to avoid placing `dostuff.py` in the root of the submodule repo since that contains other manifest files (readme, gitignore, requirements, etc), so instead I use `package/subpackage/dostuff.py` which is identical to the OP's structure. Since `subpackage` is strictly present to organize the git repo, do you think modifying `sys.modules` is bad practice in this case? If so, what would the alternative be?